# Can't access the textView ID

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, layout

I'm trying to access the textView from layout xml file. I'm using textView.text method but it's not working. I'm trying to change the text with subtraction calculation result but I can not access textView ID. You can see the problem in attached SS.[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwPvp.png) , [Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0bk3.png) , [Third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFQtP.png)

Comment: Where do you assign the textView3 variable?

Comment: I havent assigned it in onCreate but I solved the problem by using findViewById method also learned ViewBinding. Apologizing for didnt see your comment. Thank you so much. @TheLibrarian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your code.

**Example**

```
val mResultTextView = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.result)   
val mAnswer = mResultTextView .text
```

You can try **ViewBinding** - reduse error's, it remove findViewId method and boilerplate code.

Comment: Thank you so much, I learned ViewBinding and View methods and solved the problem.